# Should I learn Bootstrap & switch from WordPress?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Would you say it is worth learning Bootstrap?

I currently build custom themes for WordPress and clients from scratch using HTML, SCSS  and JS but my partner says that he builds his clients websites using Bootstrap and suggests it's a better way of doing things.

What do you think? Is building from scratch or is using Bootstrap better? What benefits does it give me changing the way I am doing things? Should I bother learning this at all?

Thanks.

Comment: Bootstrap is a frontend framework which can be applied to a WordPress theme

Comment: Yes, but would you say it's worth learning and utilising this framework or still building from scratch to allow for more customisation?

Comment: You can customise Bootstrap as much or as little as you wish. Or you can use any other front-end framework with WordPress. No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I would recommend using Bootstrap if you are learning frontend development. It has a great responsive grid system which allows you to layout your pages in different column structures for different screen sizes. It has a collection of components which are useful too.

Comment: **primarily opinion-based**
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Bootstrap is a bunch of component for developers, WordPress is a CMS that brings you a whole package already created to start a website. Bootstrap is the tools, Wordpress is pre-done.

Comment: If this question is formed with more specific inquiries, it will yield more useful responses. This doesn't have to be opinion-based matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understood the Wordpress and Bootstrap as Content Management Systems(CMS)

Bootstrap and Wordpress are totally different although they are frameworks.

Bootstrap is an extended framework for HTML and CSS. It is responsive,clean and simple.

Wordpress is a framework for PHP.

1. Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web
2. Wordpress is a best choice for beginners because of it’s ease-of-use, it works especially well for small to medium sized websites, blogs and smaller e-commerce stores.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I use WordPress as it's easy for clients to manage their own website content after building the site. I still build the website from scratch without using a theme (as I would make my own). So in this context would you say it doesn't really matter?

Comment: Generally as a developer I prefer wordpress and using bootstrap css and js in it for making it responsive, you can inform the client that we can combine both and can achieve same results

Answer (score 0):

I build websites with php, django, plain html, codeigniter(php framework), wordpress. From my experience learn bootstrap but it is just a css and js pack so if you gonna build static websites it is quite usefull in order to use wordpress. But when it comes to dynamic webpages you will need js or php or django or a server app to render the dynamic page content. Bootstrap basically a well tailored css file to fastly build client side. In these conditions you can aggregate your knowledge with bootstrap make custom themes with bootstrap for wordpress to create dynamic webpages. If your customer needs a static website then use just bootstrap with html websites.